# Filtering with a known impulse response

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have a known filter's impulse response and I want to filter my signal with it. I tried to use the matlab command filter like `filter(impulse,1,signal)` but am not sure of the result. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  How is your filter's impulse response represented as?  Filter coefficients?  A time-domain signal?  Also, I'm not sure how you'd store an analog signal in MATLAB because storing a signal there is implicitly digital / discrete.  Please show us what you've tried so we can have a better idea of what it is you're having trouble with.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry if i'm not clear enough,  I'm not familiar with signal processing. I have a binary file where are stored different impulse responses. after AM modulation, i would like to filter an audio signal with one of the impulse responses by using the filter command, something like filter(impulse,1,signal).

Comment: @rayryeng the time-domain impulse response can be used directly as FIR filter coefficients, so the OP's `filter(impulse, 1, signal)` _can_ be used.

Comment: @SleuthEye I wasn't aware. Thanks.

Comment: @WeekyCrush It looks like you're doing it properly!

Comment: @SleuthEye so would `conv(a,b)` be the same as `filter(a, 1, b)`?  This is just to satisfy my own curiosity.

Comment: @rayryeng not quite. `filter(a,1,b)` computes only `length(b)` outputs whereas `conv(a,b)` computes `length(a)+length(b)-1` outputs for the full convolution. So `conv(a,b)` would be equivalent to `filter(a,1,[b zeros(1,length(a)-1)])` (ie. convolution with a zero padded input).

Comment: @SleuthEye that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter coefficients of a [Finite Impulse Response (FIR) filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response) correspond exactly to the time domain impulse response of that same filter.

Correspondingly, you may indeed directly filter your signal with

```
filter(impulse, 1, signal);
```